# my list only displays "9" as the first index when switching

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm pretty clearly a beginner... My problem is that whenever I switch the first and last element in a random list, the first index always gets the nb "9" assigned even though there is no 9 in the list in the first place.

THX 4 help

I literally only want to switch the first and last index
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVb3v.png]

Comment: please avoid using pictures, and instead paste your code, output, and such in code blocks in your question

Comment: The first element (`z_unsort[0]`) s always assigned `9` because _you assign 9 to it_. `anzahl - 1` -> `10 - 1` -> `9`.

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [mre], and read about [ask]. Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried. Don't link screenshots of code, instead [edit] your question to include the relevant code here.

Answer (score 1):

On line 17 you assign element 0 of the array to 9

```py
z_unsort[0] = (anzahl - 1)
```

and in your output, you assigned `anzahl` to be 10

I assume this is a typo